# How to update nested object in a MongoDB collection based on the request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

**I've a collection for user given below**

```
{
  "_id": 1
  "firstname": "John"
  "lastname": "Doe"
  "address": {
    "street": "13",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "country": "USA",
    "pincode": "12345"
  }
}
```

**I want to make an API that will update the user data.**

This is what I've tried:

### First Method

Using this method some fields are being removed from collection which are not present in request.

**Query:**

```
const updateUser = (userId, data) => {
    return UserDB.updateOne({ _id: userId }, {
        $set: {...data }
    });
};
```

**Request:**

```
{
  "_id": 1
  "firstname": "Justin"
  "lastname": "Thomas"
  "address": {
    "country": "Canada",
    "pincode": "9999"
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
// street, city and state is removed from collection
{
  "_id": 1
  "firstname": "Justin"
  "lastname": "Thomas"
  "address": {
    "country": "Canada",
    "pincode": "9999"
  }
}
```

### Second Method:

Using this method, fields are set to null which are not present in the request.

**Query:**

```
const updateUser = (userId, data) => {
    return UserDB.updateOne({ _id: userId }, {
        $set: {
            "firstname": data.firstname,
            "lastname": data.lastname,
            "address.street": data.address.street,
            "address.city": data.address.city,
            "address.state": data.address.state,
            "address.country": data.address.country,
            "address.pincode": data.address.pincode
        }
    });
};
```

**Request:**

```
{
  "_id": 1
  "firstname": "Justin"
  "lastname": "Thomas"
  "address": {
    "country": "Canada",
    "pincode": "9999"
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
// street, city and state is set to null in the collection.
{
  "_id": 1
  "firstname": "Justin"
  "lastname": "Thomas"
  "address": {
    "street": null,
    "city": null,
    "state": null,
    "country": "Canada",
    "pincode": "9999"
  }
}
```

## Question

#### How can I update a nested object in a collection?

Comment: If I've understood correctly your problem you can use dot notation to not overwrite the entire document. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qtYbY9hTaYg) example.

Comment: There isn't enough info to know what is causing your problem. It would be more helpful to know what is in the `data` parameter in the `updateUser` function.

Comment: `data` consists request object that mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$addFields` in aggregation pipeline of `update` operation.

`$addFields` will only update the values that is present in the object and other fields will remain as it is.

Like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      "firstname": "Justin",
      "lastname": "Thomas",
      "address": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "pincode": "16565"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Test it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pjO8mIKb03o

Answer (score 0):

Second method is working fine [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/otQmxJTCqv8), please check your data.

Comment: It works because dot notation, note how using object [not works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PpiKj9yyTX0)

Comment: @Arvind Pal Try removing any field inside address such as `city` or `street`. It won't update in the collection

Comment: I have updated only pincode and country of address rest are as earlier.

Comment: What you've updated is already mentioned in the second approach of my question.